# Android resource compilation failed in 3.3.0-alpha02

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I try and build my project, I get this error:

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  
C:\Users\smart\AndroidStudioProjects\ShoppingList\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:497: error: :listItem>.
C:\Users\smart\AndroidStudioProjects\ShoppingList\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:498: error: :listItem>.
C:\Users\smart\AndroidStudioProjects\ShoppingList\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:499: error: :listItem>.
C:\Users\smart\AndroidStudioProjects\ShoppingList\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:503: error: :listItem>.
C:\Users\smart\AndroidStudioProjects\ShoppingList\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:504: error: :listItem>.

Command: C:\Users\smart\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.3.0-alpha02-4818971-windows.jar\a281fb5dd58b50951126c2252f73d452\aapt2-3.3.0-alpha02-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
    -o \
    C:\Users\smart\AndroidStudioProjects\ShoppingList\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
    C:\Users\smart\AndroidStudioProjects\ShoppingList\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.0-alpha02-4818971-windows Daemon #2
```

The xml lines in question are:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#d50000</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#b71c1c</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#757575</color>

<listItem name="windowActionBar">false</listItem>
<listItem name="windowNoTitle">true</listItem>
```

I am using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha02'
```

And my app gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.kellen.shoppinglist"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

implementation 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

// Room components
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1"

// Lifecycle components
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can anyone help me out? I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, and checked over all of the lines in question. I didn't even modify them recently, so I'm not sure whats going on.

**EDIT** - I've reverted my `classpath` to 3.1.3 and the `distributionUrl` to 4.5, and now I get a different error message:

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details.
```

The log says:

```
error: :listItem>.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: :listItem>., sources=`[C:\Users\smart\AndroidStudioProjects\ShoppingList\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:17:5-90], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}`
```

And points towards two different xml lines that should be valid:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/> 
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

why not to change your gradle plugin version?

First: finding how many local gradle available by looking your gradle file, 'file'->'setting'->'Build, Execuion, Deployment'->'Gradle',then you will find this file which contain a file named 'wrapper\dists', open it and you will see them.

Second: Edit file named 'gradle-wrapper.properties', and change `distributionUrl`'s value to a version which is included in your local gradle group.

Last: change the `classpath` in your `build.gradle` ,there is a [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) your can get help from it.

help you'll understand my poor English, so that i can help you:)

Comment: I've reverted my classpath to 3.1.3 and the distributionUrl to 4.5, and I get a different error message: `Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details`. The log points to different xml lines: `<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>`

Comment: is there still such a exception if you change your `style`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't konw why but this work for my project.
such as the problem,i get seam error just like your.
i fix them like this：i search error location

```html
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  F:\Works\AndroidProject\lbw\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1703: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/progress' with config ''.
F:\Works\AndroidProject\lbw\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1703: error: resource previously defined here.

Command: C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\802c7c840816e44cd175d342954a2954\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        F:\Works\AndroidProject\lbw\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        F:\Works\AndroidProject\lbw\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

then i search the file

```
F:\Works\AndroidProject\lbw\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
```

and i find the location at lines 1703
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxBlI.png)

and i find the error location in the file 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWuzo.png)

and i copy the name `absProgressBar` search in `attrs` then i get the error location
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrg6l.png)

than i commenty `<!-- <attr name="progress" format="integer" />-->` build argen the error will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

I got something similar where the Android resource compilation failed.

```
error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
```

I'm seeing some posts that suggest deleting a "ids.xml" file and that fixes the issue. While that may fix it, you may be doing more harm since code may refer to that id tag.

I fixed my issue by updating the "ids.xml" file from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="item_click_support" type="id">id</item>
</resources>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="item_click_support" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Notice how the Item tag is a self closing xml element now. This is the correct way to list id's within the "ids.xml" file now.
You can refer to the official Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id) for this as well.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When i upgrade android studio this error "Android resource compilation failed" occurred.

I search every there, but i cant find solution so i deleted three line in `values.xml`

```
<item type="id" name="id_name" />
<item name="omfm_main_label_id" type="id">OMFMLabelId</item>
<item name="omfm_tag" type="id">OMFMTag</item>
```

so it worked .
notice : all library in `build.gradle` must be upgraded.

Comment: values.xml? Where is it?