# I am getting the following errors in Android Studio “Android resource compilation failed”

Tags: android

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\Christain Sheridan\Downloads\Crisis-Response\Crisis- 
Response\app\src\main\res\layout\crisis_menu.xml:95: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command: C:\Users\Christain Sheridan\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\daf4756f8943226640d70255bc14ccd5\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
    -o \
    C:\Users\Christain Sheridan\Downloads\Crisis-Response\Crisis-Response\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
    C:\Users\Christain Sheridan\Downloads\Crisis-Response\Crisis-Response\app\src\main\res\layout\crisis_menu.xml
```

Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #1

Update: I fixed it myself, it seems that when I use a git pull from my master it puts `HEAD>>>>>>>` and more stuff that looks like a commit stuff that somehow got in there. But once I removed all of them it worked so never mind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android resource compilation failed in 3.3.0-alpha02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202130/android-resource-compilation-failed-in-3-3-0-alpha02)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52952464/8034839

Comment: Post the content of \app\src\main\res\layout\crisis_menu.xml

Answer (score 0):

it reads `crisis_menu.xml:95: error: not well-formed (invalid token)`

so you probably should check `crisis_menu.xml` at `line 95`.

and maybe use `fetch` & `rebase` instead of `pull`.